# Problem playing video files with Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 lts. My computer has a 2 x 1.86 GHz with 4 GB RAM.

I got trouble playing videos files like standard mp4 on my computer. Either i only got sound or i don't get anything. When I look into my system settings, It doesn't tell me what are my graphics drivers or infos. I've installed hardinfo to get all the informations, but if can't get anything out of it. My kind of a newby (using the terminal too...)

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install VLC by running the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```